# Beamer: frametitle continuation (bibliography) in frame subtitle

Tags: beamer

I'd like to place the `beamer`-`continuationtext` in the `framesubtitle` instead of having them in the `frametitle`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\insertframetitle\\\insertframesubtitle}
\setbeamerfont{frametitle}{size=\scriptsize}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\Large}
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}[from second][\color{gray}\insertcontinuationtext]


\usepackage[ backend = biber, style=ieee]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Knu86,
        author = {Knuth, Donald E.},
        year = {1986},
        title = {The \TeX book},
    }
    @ARTICLE{Doe2009,
        author = {Jon Doe},
        journal = {Transactions on Stuff},
        month = 03,
        number = {3},
        pages = {1--11},
        title = {{Example 1}},
        volume = {5},
        year = {2009}
    }
    @ARTICLE{Doe2010,
        author = {Jon Doe},
        journal = {More Transactions on Stuff},
        month = 05,
        number = {4},
        pages = {1--11},
        title = {{Example 2}},
        volume = {7},
        year = {2010}
    }
    @article{greenwade93,
        author  = "George D. Greenwade",
        title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
        year    = "1993",
        journal = "TUGBoat",
        volume  = "14",
        number  = "3",
        pages   = "342--351"
    }

    @book{goossens93,
        author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
        title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
        year      = "1993",
        publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
        address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
    }
    @book{author_book,
        title = {Book's title},
        author = {Author, Some},
        location = {The City},
        publisher = {Publisher},
        year = {2005},
    }
    @book{goossens96,
        author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
        title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
        edition   = "2",
        year      = "1998",
        publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
        address   = "Reading, MA, USA"
    }

    @article{Test,
        author = {Other, A. N.},
        title = {MOS Companion},
        journal = {J.~Irrep. Res.},
        month = {3},
        year    = {2011},
        pages   = {1-10}
    }
        @book{authbook,
            title = {Book's title},
            author = {Author, Any},
            location = {City},
            publisher = {Publisher},
            year = {2015},
        }
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{title}{subtitle}
    test
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Literature} 
    \nocite{*}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would be possible to redefine the `\framesubtitle{ }` to something like `\framesubtitle[from second]{...}` to change the subtitle at the first `framebreak` (ie the second biblography page).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can remove the `\usebeamertemplate*{frametitle continuation}` part of the `\beamer@@frametitle` definition and add it instead to your frametitle template.

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\insertframetitle\\\insertframesubtitle\usebeamertemplate*{frametitle continuation}}

\makeatletter
\long\def\beamer@@frametitle[#1]#2{%
  \beamer@ifempty{#2}{}{%
    \gdef\insertframetitle{{#2\ifnum\beamer@autobreakcount>0\relax{}\fi}}%
  \gdef\beamer@frametitle{#2}%
  \gdef\beamer@shortframetitle{#1}%
}%
}
\makeatother
```